# Laravel tables in project and in mysql

Tags: laravel

Hello guys I appreciate any help in advanced,
Here is my problem:
I am doing some models like Image (class Image extends Model), Video(class Video extends Model), Post(class Post extends Model) and User(class User extends Model) with their tables in plural like(e.g.) protected $table=images; and so...  in App/Database in my project.

I have already done...but I am not sure how those tables must be related in mysql used in server and if I am not sure if I should create those table in my server in myqsl and if so where should I put those in server...

I am really stuck here for 3 days, ...

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Just FYI, if your tables names are plural versions of the model name you don't need to add `protected $table ...` as Laravel will assume this as default.

Comment: I'm not quite getting your question. Are you asking how to create the tables? Or how to connect to your database? Or how to install mysql? ...or something else entirely?

Comment: Did you create the migrations files?

Comment: what I ask is:  how can I connect my  " models(created in laravel) "  to MySQL located in web server

Comment: btw thanks for all your information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion to you is to create your models using the PHP Artisan, follows the syntax:

```
php artisan make:model User
```

In this case the Artisan will create everything that is necessary and once your model is properly created you can customize it to your project.

Comment: this is best way for create model file .

Comment: yes you`r  right, models are already created. But I do not know how to see tables in MySQL located in webserver.

Comment: migrate doe not work properly, only migrate one table called users and not the rest...that's way I want to do it manually.